# How to select SQL date by keeping Month and day and changing Year to current?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Stored Proc in SQL Server that I am working on updated and trying to come up with a way to change the year in a date (only the year).

**Example:** Date is 01/05/2010 and at selection, I need the date to 01/05/2017.

Comment: What should happen to e.g. Feb 29, 2012 (Leap day)? The date Feb 29, 2017 does not exist.

Comment: @PeterB, then it will display Feb 28, 2017.

Comment: @Madhukar you can't speak for the OP, only John (hopefully) knows what his requirements are.

Comment: Peter: Yes, it should be the 28th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the current year,

```
SELECT DateAdd(YEAR, YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(date_field), date_field) FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `datefromparts`, if your SQL Server version is >=2012

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),
            DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()),
                          DATEPART(MONTH, '01/05/2010'),
                          DATEPART(DAY, '01/05/2010')), 103)
```

Comment: DATEFROMPARTS() is v2012 fyi.

Comment: Your second and third arguments are backwards.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff.Corrected it